# Combining Bot Framework Composer with custom C# Code

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am using the [Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction?tabs=v2x) to create a bot using some actions. While a lot can be done from within the composer I need to add some "special" actions that only can be achieved by code and not from within the composer.

I am aware that the composer creates a solution and project which contains the bot code. There also is a `BotController` and `SkillsController` created. I would expect that I have to attach my code somewhere in those controllers but cannot find any documentation on this.

For the beginning I just want to achieve something very simple like displaying a text as described at the [bot framework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

I just need to know where to inject the code for a solution created by the composer

TL;DR: How do I combine Dot Framework SDK - Code with the Bot Framework Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical pattern for adding custom code to a composer bot is through the use of custom actions and custom triggers. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions) and [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/composer-samples/csharp_dotnetcore/projects/CustomAction/MultiplyDialog) should help explain how to implement them.